# Entity framework incorrect data returned from linq select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to using entity framework, so maybe I'm doing something really wrong, but the following code isn't working the way I'd expect it to:

```
PRODUCTEntities dbCustomerRefresh = new PRODUCTEntities();
Int16 delay = 5000;
while(true)
{
    var pendingFaults = (from f in dbCustomerRefresh.Faults where f.lRefreshStatus == 1 select f);
    foreach(Fault f in pendingFaults)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("Initial refresh status for fault {0} is {1}", f.lFaultID.ToString(), f.lRefreshStatus.ToString());
        f.lRefreshStatus = 2;
        log.DebugFormat("Changed Refresh status for fault: {0} to {1}", f.lFaultID.ToString(),f.lRefreshStatus.ToString());
    }
    log.DebugFormat("Saved {0} rows to LOSCH Database",dbCustomerRefresh.SaveChanges().ToString());
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
}
```

This works as expected the first time round the loop, I.e. it picks up every row in the DB that has the lRefreshStatus set to 1,  changes it to 2 and prints it to debug.

I then go into the database and manually change the lRefreshStatus back to 1 for a given row. On the next loop round, my program picks up that the status has changed again, but the initial values in the variable are wrong.

```
2015-07-30 09:27:17,137 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Initial refresh status for fault 101380 is 1
2015-07-30 09:27:17,137 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Changed Refresh status for fault: 101380 to 2
2015-07-30 09:27:17,292 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 1 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:22,297 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:27,304 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:32,313 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:37,318 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:42,327 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:47,336 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:52,341 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:27:57,346 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:02,356 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:07,361 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:12,366 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:17,371 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:22,378 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:27,384 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:32,390 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:37,396 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:42,405 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Initial refresh status for fault 101380 is 2
2015-07-30 09:28:42,405 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Changed Refresh status for fault: 101380 to 2
2015-07-30 09:28:42,405 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
2015-07-30 09:28:47,410 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Initial refresh status for fault 101380 is 2
2015-07-30 09:28:47,410 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Changed Refresh status for fault: 101380 to 2
2015-07-30 09:28:47,411 [10] DEBUG CustomerService - Saved 0 rows to PRODUCT Database
```

Its bizarre. The select must pick up that the value of the fault status has changed to 1 or it wouldn't be in the pendingFaults variable, but when I then go to access that property, its set to 2.

Does it not dispose of the old f variable from the first time around, and just give me that back again on the second loop?

Comment: Your querying the cached data move `PRODUCTEntities dbCustomerRefresh = new PRODUCTEntities();` into the loop

Comment: If I'm querying cached data, then why does my select return anything when I change the data manually in the backend?

Comment: Ok strange, what happens if you move the creation of the context into the loop, still same behaviour?

Comment: That works, but surely disposing and creating a new dbcontext every time I want to get rid of a cached row isn't the right way to do things. That seems like an awful lot of overhead for a very small operation.

Comment: Ok now we know what the problem is try using `AsNoTracking` on the query and see if it stops the data from caching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812608/ef-dbcontext-how-to-avoid-caching

Comment: That doesn't have the desired effect. If I do this, then the updates never get written to the database.

Comment: Yea to save you'll need to attach them and set their `State` correctly to save.  Easiest way will just be to move the context creation into the loop

Answer (score 0):

Check like this.

```
PRODUCTEntities dbCustomerRefresh = new PRODUCTEntities();
Int16 delay = 5000;
while(true)
{
    var pendingFaults = (from f in dbCustomerRefresh.Faults where f.lRefreshStatus == 1 select f);
    foreach(Fault f in pendingFaults)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("Initial refresh status for fault {0} is {1}", f.lFaultID.ToString(), f.lRefreshStatus.ToString());
        f.lRefreshStatus = 2;
        log.DebugFormat("Changed Refresh status for fault: {0} to {1}", f.lFaultID.ToString(),f.lRefreshStatus.ToString());
log.DebugFormat("Saved {0} rows to LOSCH Database",dbCustomerRefresh.SaveChanges().ToString());
    }

Thread.Sleep(delay);
}
```

See if it makes difference.

Comment: System.Data.EntityException: {"New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."}. <- This happens on the savechanges line

Comment: @JJ The foreach loop is the culprit, correct it. see the post for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther

Comment: I had a look at this post earlier. Maybe it's because I'm not using the same version of EF, but this doesn't work for me. Worth noting Entity object is a DBContext, but in the example you gave it's an ObjectContext.